# My Capistrano does not set the RAILS_ENV variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

My Capistrano deployment does not set the RAILS_ENV variable when running the bundle command. I don't understand why.

My Gemfile is :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.3'

gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'
```

My deploy.rb :

```
set :stage, :production
set :rails_env, 'production'

set :bundle_flags, '--deployment'
set :bundle_env_variables, { rails_env: "production" }

namespace :sphinx do
  desc "Index Sphinx"
  task :index do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
      execute :rake, "rake ts:index"
    end
  end
end
```

When running :

```
➜  ansible-sharetribe git:(master) ✗ bin/cap production sphinx:index --trace
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke sphinx:index (first_time)
** Execute sphinx:index
INFO[3ca70ab5] Running bundle exec rake rake ts:index on www.myapplication.com
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host www.myapplication.com: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Annotate
```

If I write :

```
execute :rake, "rake ts:index RAILS_ENV=production"
```

it works. Why is RAILS_ENV=production not set automatically?

Comment: Have you found the answer? Looks like I faced the same problem ...

Comment: I have the same problem. Ran across a lot of fixes, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax in your task

```
execute :rake, "rake ts:index", "RAILS_ENV=#{fetch :rails_env}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
I ran rake secret and got "NameError: uninitialized constant Annotate" error.
After i set RAILS_ENV=production, it worked like charm.
I dont know why RAILS_ENV wasnt set but BTW thanks so much.
Saved me a lot of time